# Write Large File Listing To File Efficiently in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, file

I have what I would consider to be a fairly common problem, but have not managed to find a good solution on my own or by browsing this forum.

**Problem**

I have written a tool to get a file listing of a folder with some additional information such as file name, file path, file size, hash, etc.

The biggest problem that I have is that some of the folders contain millions of files (maybe 50 million in the structure).

**Possible Solutions**

I have two solutions, but neither of them are ideal.

1. Every time a file is read, the information is written straight to file.  This is OK, but it means I can't multi-thread the file without running into issues with the thread locking the file.
2. Every time a file is read, the information is added to some form of collection such as a ConcurrentBag.  The means I can multi-thread the enumeration of the files and add them to the collection.  Once the enumeration is done, I can write the whole collection to a file using File.WriteAllLines; however adding 50 million entries to the collection makes most machines run out of memory.

**Other Options**

Is there any way to add items to a collection and then write them to a file when it gets to a certain number of records in the collection or something like that?

I looked into a BlockingCollection, but that will just fill up really quickly as the producer will be multi-threaded, but the consumer would only be single-threaded.

Comment: You can go with your option 2 but flush it to file once number of entries is bigger than some predefined threshold i.e. write to file & clean your concurrent bag periodically.

Comment: Side note: disk (and all other I/O operations) is generally I/O bound rather than CPU bound - running such operations in multi-threaded manner against single source will not necessary improve performance (and possibly slow things down). Main reason people do that is that writing such code is more interesting than single threaded operation - makes sure you know that reason you are doing it aligns with your goals.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, thanks for this.  This application is for use on storage servers so IO should not be the same issue as running it on the disk of a single machine.

Comment: I agree with @AlexeiLevenkov, I doubt this is a scenario where multi-threading would actually increase the performance, but rather slow it down. But do some tests a try it out.

Comment: If you're not using it, the [DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.enumeratefiles(v=vs.110).aspx) might be useful. You didn't show any code, so I had to suggest it.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  How would I actually flush the collection to a file and not miss the last chunk of data.  E.g.  If I flush it every 1000 files and the last chunk is 50 files then I will miss those 50.

I will do some testing on the multi-threading, but as it is to be used on servers running RAID, I hope it will speed it up.

I am using DirectoryInfo.Enumerate files.  This gets the files, but it is what I do with it after which is the issue.

Comment: from my experience .NET seems to be one of the slowest ways to retrieve file information even with multithreading. You can try comparing to Scripting.FileSystemObject for example

Comment: You should not multi thread.  It is one read write head on the other end.  multi thread is not going to make that go faster.   I would use a blocking collection where you read on one side and write on another.   Write to a separate physical (SSD) disk.   Chunk the writes.

Comment: @Ninja You said "This application is for use on storage servers" - have you *actually* tested in on a storage server as well as your local storage? You didn't mention that.

Comment: `BlockingCollection` sounds like exactly what you want - if you run out you WANT it to block the producers until the single consumer catches up. Also, why would it 'fill up quickly'? It's writing sequentially to a single file it keeps open while the other threads are reading large files and calculating hashes on them. Have you tried it?

Comment: @Ninja, do you expect a draft implementation as an answer?

Comment: To answer some of the questions, I tried multi-threaded and it was faster than single-threaded.  That makes sense to me because the storage server could have up to 24 disks and the controller would handle spreading the data across those disks.  Thanks for everyone's help. I went for the producer / consumer with a BlockingCollection in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Create a FileStream that is shared by all threads. Before writing to that FileStream, a thread must lock it. FileStream has some buffer (4096bytes if i remember right), so it doesn't actually write to disk every time. You may use a BufferedStream around that if 4096 bytes is still not enough.

Answer (score 1):

`BlockingCollection` is precisely what you need. You can create one with a large buffer and have a single writer thread writing to a file that it keeps open for the duration of the run.

If reading is the dominant operation time-wise the queue will be near empty the whole time and total time will be just slightly more than the read time.

If writing is the dominant operation time-wise the queue will fill up until you reach the limit you set (to prevent out of memory situations) and producers will only advance as the writer advances. The total time will be the time needed to write all the records to a single file sequentially and you cannot do better than that (when writer is the slowest part).

You may be able to get slightly better performance by pipelining through multiple blocking collections, e.g. making the hash-calculation (a CPU-bound operation) potentially separate from the read, or write operations. If you want to do that though consider the TPL DataFlow library.